# Wait for separate data class to get data from firestore before updating tableView in viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a separate class which loads and stores my data from firestore.
In my view controller I create an instance of the data class, and in viewdidload I call dataClass.pullfromfirestore(), which loads my firestore data into the class.

I need to wait for firebase to fetch my data, and then reload my tableview. How do I do this?

If  my pullfromfirestore function was in my view controller I could call dispatchqueue.main.async{tableview.reloadData()} inside the function , but of course this function is another class so I cant do that.

Comment: *I need to wait*. You don't. Reload the table view inside the asynchronous completion closure or use a way to **notify** when the data is available.

Comment: where do I put the asynchonous completition closure though? I can't put it in my data class

Comment: Then add another completion handler in `pullfromfirestore()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to pass a callback function of some sort -- a function that gets called when the Firestore call is complete.

Something like:

```
func pullFromFirestore(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
  let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF")

  docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
        completion() //<-- Here
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
  }
}
```

And in your view controller:

```
dataClass.pullFromFirestore(completion: { [weak self] in
  dispatchqueue.main.async{ self?.tableview.reloadData() }
})
```

You could get even fancier and pass your data back through that callback function if you wanted.

Comment: thanks thats great, never encountered callback functions before